# Provider is not updating the value of variable in the UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, provider, flutter-provider

I am using a global variable in one of my class. The value of that global variable is null at start but it get value after some time from a function that is running in the background. I want that when the value of that global variable is changed, its value should also updated to UI. I am using provider for that. but provider is not updating the value of that varible automatically on the UI and I have to revisit the screen to show the updated value. check my code and let me know what's wrong with my code and why it is not updating the value of variable in realtime on the UI.

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ProfilePicProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _profilepic = ''; // Initialize it with an empty string.

  String get profilepic => _profilepic;

  void updateProfilePic(String newProfilePic) {
    _profilepic = newProfilePic;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Above is my Provider Model.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) {
            return themeChangeProvider;
          }),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<ProfilePicProvider>.value(
            value: ProfilePicProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child:
        Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(builder: (context, themeData, child) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Shoot Your Shot',
            theme: Styles.themeData(themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, context),
            home: bottomNavigation(currentIndex: 0),
          );
        }));
  }
```

This is how I am calling it in the main.dart file.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:datingapp/Screens/Dialogs/DeleteAccountDialog.dart';
import 'package:datingapp/Screens/EditProfile/EditProfile.dart';
import 'package:datingapp/Screens/MainScreens/UpdateEmail.dart';
import 'package:datingapp/Widgets/GradientSwitch.dart';
import 'package:datingapp/Widgets/GradientText.dart';
import 'package:datingapp/Widgets/loading.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../../Onboarding/Upgrade.dart';
import '../../ThemeChange/_providerModel.dart';
import '../../global_variables.dart';
import '../../provider/ProfilePicProvider.dart';
import 'BlockedUsers.dart';
import 'FilterScreen.dart';
import 'Notifications.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({super.key});

  @override
  State<Profile> createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  String? userFirstname = name?.split(' ')[0];
  String? age = "$userAge";
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("user Images are: $userImagesList");
    print("user profile pic is: $profilepic");
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Provider.of<ProfilePicProvider>(context, listen: false).updateProfilePic(profilepic);
    final themeChange = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 850,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/profilebg2.png"),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => openFiltersBottomSheet(context),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/images/gradient-filter-icon.png",
                                      width: 33,
                                      height: 33)),
                              GradientText(TextWidget: const Text(
                                'Profile',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(width: 33)
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 30),
                          Consumer<ProfilePicProvider>(
                            builder: (context, profilePicProvider, child) {
                              return Stack(
                              children: [
                              Container(
                              width: 150,
                              height: 150,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle),
                              child: profilepic != null ? ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200), child: Image.file(File(profilepic!), fit: BoxFit.cover)) : null,
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                              right: 3,
                              bottom: 3,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => Get.to(EditProfile()),
                              child: Container(
                          width: 34,
                          height: 34,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                          color: Color(0xffC7C7CC)),
                          child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 20,
                          )),
                          ),
                          ),
                          ),
                          ],
                          );
                            },
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: '$userFirstname ',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Avenir",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                color:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium?.color,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: age,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 165,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                colors: [Color(0xff6814CE), Color(0xff296FF9)],
                                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(height: 10),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text("Shoot Your Shot ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 20)),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                                      child: Container(
                                          width: 75,
                                          height: 33,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                  image: AssetImage(
                                                      "assets/images/whitebg-text.png"),
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: [
                                                GradientText(TextWidget: Text(
                                                  'M.V.P ',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                  ),
                                                )),
                                                Image.asset(
                                                  "assets/images/trophy-emoji.png",
                                                  width: 11,
                                                  height: 13,
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 15),
                                RichText(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                    text: 'First 3 days free!',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                      color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                      fontSize: 16.5,
                                    ),
                                    children: [
                                      TextSpan(
                                        text: '\nthen just \$19.97 / month',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          height: 1.2,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontSize: 12.5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => Get.to(Upgrade()),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                                    height: 35,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: GradientText(TextWidget: Text(
                                        'Free Trial Upgrade',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ))
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 350,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                                color: Color(0x39D9D9D9)),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  CustomFeaturesWidget(
                                      label: "Shots",
                                      description:
                                          "Never run out of likes again with unlimited shots",
                                      gradientText: "Unlimited",
                                      iconPath:
                                          "assets/images/shots-icon-rounded.png"),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  CustomFeaturesWidget(
                                      label: "Chat Substitions",
                                      description:
                                          "The first three chats are on us! Thereafter,  remove and replace unlimited chats at will",
                                      gradientText: "Unlimited",
                                      iconPath:
                                          "assets/images/close-icon-rounded.png"),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  CustomFeaturesWidget(
                                      label: "See Who Likes You",
                                      description:
                                          "Find out who is shooting their shot at you",
                                      gradientText: "Unlimited",
                                      iconPath:
                                          "assets/images/eyes-icon-rounded.png"),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  CustomFeaturesWidget(
                                      label: "Go backs",
                                      description:
                                          "Change of heart? Go back for another chance to like a users profile",
                                      gradientText: "Unlimited",
                                      iconPath: "assets/images/goback-icon.png"),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  CustomFeaturesWidget(
                                      label: "Ads",
                                      description:
                                          "Focus on shooting your shot to find your match & never see an ad again!",
                                      gradientText: "NO ADS",
                                      iconPath: "assets/images/cross-icon.png"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        CustomMenuWidget(
                            title: "Edit Email",
                            onClick: () => Get.to(UpdateEmail())),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(
                            title: "Blocked Users",
                            onClick: () => Get.to(BlockedUsers())),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(title: "Rate Us", onClick: () {}),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(title: "Invite a friend", onClick: () {}),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(
                            title: "Notifications",
                            onClick: () => Get.to(Notifications())),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(
                            title: "Send Support Email", onClick: () {}),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(title: "Safety Center", onClick: () {}),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(title: "Terms of Service", onClick: () {}),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        CustomMenuWidget(title: "Privacy Policy", onClick: () {}),
                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                        Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text("Dark Mode",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .labelMedium
                                          ?.color,
                                      fontSize: 15)),
                              CustomSwitch(
                                activeColor: Colors.transparent,
                                value: themeChange.darkTheme,
                                onChanged: (bool value) {
                                  themeChange.darkTheme = value;
                                },
                              ),
                            ]),
                        SizedBox(height: 50),
                        GradientText(TextWidget: Text(
                          'Log out',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )),
                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                        Text("Restore my purchases",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .inputDecorationTheme
                                    .hintStyle
                                    ?.color,
                                fontSize: 14)),
                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => DeleteAccountDialog.showResponseDialog(),
                          child: Text("Delete my account",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: Color(0xffF18A80),
                                  fontSize: 14)),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Text("v1.0.0",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .inputDecorationTheme
                                    .hintStyle
                                    ?.color,
                                fontSize: 11)),
                        SizedBox(height: 30)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: isLoading,
                child: Loading(topPadding: 0))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above the code of class where I am using the value of global variable profilepic and provider.

```
String? imageUrl;
String profilepic = '';
List<String> userImagesList =[];
String? emailAddress;
String? name;
String? userBio;
String? userGender;
List<String> userGreenFlags = [];
List<String> userRedFlags = [];
int? userAge;
DateTime? userDOB;
```

And this is where my global variable **profilepic** is stored.

I am noew to provider and don't know enough about that. let me know what changes I need to make to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

In **build()** method you're updating the profile pic using provider
and Consumer is using **profilePic** which is a global variable, you should be using profilePic from your provider. example:

```
Consumer<ProviderClassName>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                return NetworkImage(provider.profilePic);
              },
            ),
```

consumer here is watching the provider.profilePic, whenever it updates it will rebuild **NetworkImage** Widget.

Comment: is there any other changes required bcz it is still not working. Now it is not even showing profile pic after restarting that screen